# Trouble understanding, implementing and then using multiprocessing module in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am experimenting with python **multiprocessing module** and now I have got a task to complete via using multiprocessing . I have already tried many ways of doing it, but I always end up either with:

1. An endless cycle creating subprocesses
2. An absurdly slower time than when running it regularly
3. A straightforward error regarding syntax or other (for me completelly foreign) different errors

Here is **one** of my functions, that I would need to speed up via multiprocessing:

```
def CosineEvaluation(dictOfElements, nestedDictOfFiles):
    upperHalf = 0
    lowerHalfLeft = 0
    lowerHalfRight = 0
    nestedKeys = []
    resultsList = []
    result = 0


 for evaluationNum in range(len(nestedDictOfFiles)):

        for keys in nestedDictOfFiles["file" + str(evaluationNum)].keys():
            nestedKeys.append(str(keys))

        howManyKeys = len(nestedDictOfFiles["file" + str(evaluationNum)])
        print(howManyKeys)
        dictOfElementsCopy = dictOfElements
        if(len(dictOfElements) < howManyKeys):
            for emptyValue in range(len(dictOfElements), howManyKeys):
                dictOfElementsCopy["empty" + str(emptyValue+1)] = 0
        
        for key, value in dictOfElementsCopy.items():
            for itemCount in range(len(nestedDictOfFiles["file" + str(evaluationNum)])):
                if(nestedKeys[itemCount] == key): 
                    upperHalf += value * nestedDictOfFiles["file" + str(evaluationNum)][nestedKeys[itemCount]]  
                lowerHalfRight += value ** 2        
                lowerHalfLeft += nestedDictOfFiles["file" + str(evaluationNum)][nestedKeys[itemCount]] ** 2  


        result = (math.sqrt(upperHalf)  / (math.sqrt(lowerHalfLeft) + math.sqrt(lowerHalfRight))) * 100
        result = round(result, 5)
        resultsList.append(f"Percentage of file no. {evaluationNum} is: " + str(result) + " %")

        indexWord = 0
        upperHalf = 0
        lowerHalfLeft = 0
        lowerHalfRight = 0
        nestedKeys.clear()

    print(resultsList)
```

I understand and very well know, that this function is (probably) an algorithmic hell (when regarding speed) but one of the conditions for this task was *not* to use any additional libraries besides the basic ones (that essentially means that I can use native Python libraries and Numpy). Also, I am learning and I want to make better programs eventually. But that is not that relevant now.
The function I put there is just one of the functions that are in the project, but they are basically all the same code-wise (nested loops and various calculations). Would it be possible for me to refactor the code to work with multiple processes? If yes, could anyone please show me the way to do it on this function?
Thanks alot in advance :)

Comment: It just does not make any sense to use multiprocessing here, because if your PC works at 100% CPU, it won't get faster by splitting the calculations into multiple processes. In fact, AFAIK it should even be slower, because all the variables need to be created once for every process, instead of only one time. If you want your code to be faster, you need to make it faster in itself (clean up the "algorithmic hell")

Comment: I apologize that I did not mention it - CPU is not at 100% when the code is running, it is merely chilling at 20%, hence why I am looking for improvement, because there is CPU space to be filled I think.

Comment: Okay, you are right, 20% CPU are quite depressing. But, yould you add the code where you got "A straightforward error regarding syntax or other (for me completelly foreign) different errors" and post these errors, too ?

Comment: I figured out, that those errors were caused by badly written code - you see I am quite new to multiprocessing so I had to google a bit to find out what was wrong. Still though, despite me fixing that issue, I end up in an endless loop of subprocesses being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem I had was indeed something I would have never thought of - Windows behaves completelly differently than Linux when regarding threads/subprocesses. That means, that without a pre-defined main function and a split function, that (as the name suggests) splits the algorithm into integer parts (not decimal!), you can't convince the interpreter to track those processes correctly. So, create a split function, create main function and call it from there - looks like problem solved, program is running aprox 3-4 times faster now.